# mvc action name in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

UPDATE:

My model going into the save method is PartialViewModel, which in the save method, is pushed into the index's ContactViewModel and sent back. This wasn't clear.

I am playing around with MVC3, and have a contact controller with a SaveDetails action. The index cshtml has a partial with a form whose action is pointing to this controller.

When I submit the form not having completed it fully, thereby firing the validation, the url now contains the SaveDetails action name (http://localhost:7401/Contact/SaveDetails).

The form code is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveDetails", "Contact")) {
    ...
}
```

The controller action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult SaveDetails(Models.PartialsViewModel pvm)
{
    return View("Index", new ContactViewModel{ PartialsViewModel = pvm } );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The form has the action attribute set to SaveDetails action, so after submit it redirects the browser to this action.

Comment: So how do I make it not do that, and just redirect it to the original index method with the model?  There are two forms on the page, which is why they are not just posting to the index method, but another action.

Answer (score 0):

I don' think you are doing anything wrong but I don't think you are able to do what you are tying to achieve. A request has to go somewhere and in mvc the url is used to identify which action you want to perform. If you are not submitting a post back then the url is going to change.

One way to submit the forms to different actions would be using some ajax.

Submitting the form is a POST. You can use an attribute to identify what request method an action should respond to. This means that you can create another action also called Index but give it the [HttpPost] attribute.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Models.ContactViewModel cvm)
{
    return View();
}
```

This way it won't display the action in the url.

Comment: I have two forms on the page, each with their own model, which is why I'm not posting to an index action.

Comment: You could use ajax to submit each form to different actions and not display the acton in the url.

Comment: I am going to use javascript, but only when I have it working as standard posts.